# Making image using UIGravityBehavior fall from random locations

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I'm following this tutorial: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/ios-7-how-to-use-uigravitybehavior/ which I have managed to get working great (Thanks to the helpful video). However I would now like to make the *image fall from random locations. How would I go about implementing this?

Here is the .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
@property (nonatomic) UIDynamicAnimator *animator;

-(IBAction)Start;
```

Here is the .m file:

```
@synthesize animator = _animator;

-(IBAction)Start {
    _animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
    UIGravityBehavior *gravityBehavior = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc]     initWithItems:@[self.image]];
    [_animator addBehavior:gravityBehavior];
}
```

Comment: So what is exactly the part you have problem with? Setting the initial random location?

Comment: Yes, This tutorial drags the image to the main storyboard but I want it to so that when the app loads the image starts at a different location then falls. Make sense?